# Texting and phone I am texting is asking for my name

Tags: iphone, messages

I have my neighbor's phone number and he said that I could let him know if I needed any help moving.  When I went to text him, it seemed like his phone required my name or it wouldn't let me text him. First of all, how would his phone do this? And, second, why would I have to give a name?  Is this my iPhone 4 doing this or his phone?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are just trying to send a regular text.

Here's how to do it:
Open the **Messages** app, (tap "Messages" in the upper left corner if you are in a thread), tap the **compose** icon, enter the recipients phone number (I've never had it ask for my name), then type your text.

If you are using the Messages app, it should not ask you for your name.